# How can i read and query my own sqlite file in windows phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to read my own sqlite file in my application. I'm using sqlite-net but it is not working. Please guide me how can i read and query my own sqlite file?

Answer (score 0):

**Try these links:**

These references will help you to read and query sqlite in Windows Phone:

[MSDN Tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Using-Sqlite-with-WP8-52c3c671)

[Visual Studio Magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/11/01/Retrieving-Storing-and-Displaying-Data.aspx?Page=1)

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/642845/SQLite-for-Windows-Phone)

Comment: @MuhammadUmair- I have shared few more links,refer and try to implement.Don't  forget to vote up and to mark as an answer if my answer solved your problem.

Comment: sqlite project is not adding into it please guide me it is producing an error, i will mark it when problem will solve

Comment: @MuhammadUmair-What type of error you are getting.Please post your error message.

Comment: unable to read the project file was not found . But file is in folder